# magento product details page showing 404 error

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

One of my magento site was running good, from today product details url showing 404 error, it is not viewing product details, catalog search, product listing on category, everything is fine but only details page is  showing 404 error,

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check if the url rewrites are enabled:
System> Configuration > Web > Search Engine Optimization > Use Web Server Rewrites

If so, you need to enable the mod_rewrite, or make sure that you have it in your Web Server.

Answer (score 0):

Check your exception.log file. If you are getting REPORT_EVEN_TYPE errors, run this SQL query in your db.

```
INSERT INTO `report_event_types` (`event_type_id`, `event_name`, `customer_login`) VALUES
(1, 'catalog_product_view', 1),
(2, 'sendfriend_product', 1),
(3, 'catalog_product_compare_add_product', 1),
(4, 'checkout_cart_add_product', 1),
(5, 'wishlist_add_product', 1),
(6, 'wishlist_share', 1);
```

Do add prefix to your tables if you have one.